# date picker not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery

This code works properly on a simple HTML page, but does not work on a CodeIgniter view.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Datepicker Popups calender to Choose date
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            $("#format").change(function() {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", $(this).val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="selected_date" id="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: this should not be the case. Are you including the `js` file. using `base_url()`

Comment: You don't need the anonymous function `$(function() { .... }` - you can put your code directly into the document ready function. Are there any errors shown in the console?

Comment: What error showing in console?